# How to use Ext.state.Manager with localStorage instead cookies?

Tags: extjs, cookies, state

Ext JS Ext.state.Manager has only Coockie  provider. Cookie can hold only 4096 bites and if my grid or tree has many columns - it overflow 4096 bites and cant save state. 
one else issue - every request to server sends all cookies in request, so Apache or anoter web server can not permit huge cookies.

I want to use Provider to save data in localStorage. Is any ready solution? Or I have to write it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is workaround that I use for now, but may be any more complex solution?

```
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.CookieProvider({
    setCookie : function(name, value){
       var me = this;
       localStorage.setItem(me.prefix+name,me.encodeValue(value));
    },
    clearCookie : function(name){
        var me = this;
        localStorage.removeItem(me.prefix+name);
    },
    readCookies : function(){
        var prefix = this.prefix,
            len = prefix.length,
            cookies = {};
            keys = Object.keys(localStorage),
            i = 0;
        for (; i < keys.length; i++) {
            console.log(keys[i].substring(0, len));
            if (keys[i] && keys[i].substring(0, len) == prefix){
            cookies[keys[i].substr(len)]= this.decodeValue(localStorage.getItem(keys[i]));
        }
    }
        return cookies;
    }
}));
```

Comment: I'm stuck with Ext 2.x, and this code helped me a lot! I enhanced it by adding getCookie() function, to get items from the local storage, and also IE has problems with using Object.keys function (not defined), so I needed to define it before using it, as per this website: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: Man you make my day! I check your code in ExtJs 4.2.1 and it works great. You're awesome.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider` has been added to ExtJS in [Ext JS 4 Beta 1](https://www.iteye.com/blog/yesjavame-1073812) released on March 30, 2011. See original [Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.2/#!/api/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider) and [Implementation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.0/source/LocalStorageProvider.html#Ext-state-LocalStorageProvider) and current [Docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/classic/Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider.html) and [Implementation](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.5.1/classic/src/LocalStorageProvider.js.html) as of March 11, 2022.

```js
Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(new Ext.state.LocalStorageProvider());
```